strapi issue when yarn build: spawn EPERM
[ERROR]  There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                     │
│   Error: spawn EPERM                                                                                                                │
│       at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)                                                                    │
│       at Object.spawn (node:child_process:762:9)                                                                                    │
│       at ensureServiceIsRunning (E:\projet-dev\la-cannaille\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1963:29)   │
│       at startSyncServiceWorker (E:\projet-dev\la-cannaille\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2169:19)   │
│       at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projet-dev\la-cannaille\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2210:3)        │
│       at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)                                                                 │
│       at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)                                                                      │
│       at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)                                                                     │
│       at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)                                                                  │
│       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)                                        │
│                                                                                                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

i got this error in a fresh new strapi project... have you any idea from where it could come from?

found the issue, was my antivirus software which was blocking my build.
i close the issue
